# Sufficient condition for almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, measure-theory

The following criterion for almost sure convergence is available on books or over internet: Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be a sequence of random variables, if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_n-X|> \epsilon)$ is finite, then $X_n \to X$ almost surely. My question is that, can $\epsilon$ be replaced by some sequence which depends on $n$, say for example $n \epsilon$ ?

Comment: Can you think of a simple example where $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_n-X|> \epsilon)$ is infinite for some $\epsilon$ but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_n-X|> n \epsilon)$ is finite, perhaps with $X=0$ and $X_n$ independent? Then apply the converse of the [Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result)

Answer (score 0):

In general the answer is no: you cannot modify the Borel-Cantelli lemma this way.

As a simple case, let's try to replace $\epsilon$ with $n \epsilon$. As a counterexample, consider setting $X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots = 1$ and $X = 0$ with probability $1$. Then clearly $\{X_n\}$ does not converge to $X$. However, for any $\epsilon$, the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(|X_n - X| > n \epsilon)$ is finite, because we know that $|X_n - X| = 1$, so $P(|X_n - X| > n \epsilon) = 0$ for all $n > 1 / \epsilon$.

This counterexample generalizes to various sequences where $\epsilon$ depends on $n$, for example $\sqrt{n} \epsilon$. Of course, there are *some* sequences where this is allowed: for example, if you replace $\epsilon$ with $\epsilon / n$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon) < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon / n)$.