# Showing ${X_n\over n^{1/\alpha}}\to 0$ a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of iids with $\Bbb EX_1 =0$ and let $\alpha>0$ be a constant. If $\Bbb E|X_1|^\alpha<\infty$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}{X_n\over n^{1/\alpha}} = 0$ a.s.

Since $\Bbb P(|X_1|^\alpha>x)$ is a decreasing in $x$,
\begin{align*}
\infty>\Bbb E|X_1|^\alpha & = \int_0^\infty\Bbb P(|X_1|^\alpha>x)dx\\
& \geq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Bbb P(|X_1|^\alpha>n)\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\Bbb P(|X_n|^\alpha>n).
\end{align*}
Then by Borel-Cantelli lemma, $\Bbb P(|X_1|>n^{1/\alpha}, \text{i.o}) = 0$. This is far from sufficient and I don't know how to use $\Bbb EX_1 =0$ condition here. Could you help?

Comment: It's a well known theorem that if $\sum_{n}P(|Y_{n}|>\epsilon)<\infty$ for each $\epsilon$ then $Y_{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron That's Borel-Cantelli isn't it? It seems I can just simply multiply $k$ at $X_1$ and do the same argument as in the answer.

Comment: Yes, that is Borel Cantelli but applied a countable number of times. For each $k$ (in the answer) you will get a set of measure $0$ outside which you won't get jumps of size more than $\frac{1}{k}$ after a while. Now you have to take the union over all such sets indexed $k$(which will still have measure 0 due to union bound) outside of which you will not get a jump of size $\frac{1}{k}$ for any $k$ after a while (which is same as convergence of a sequence).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\infty >\Bbb Ek|X_1|^\alpha  = \int_0^\infty\Bbb P(k|X_1|^\alpha>x)dx\\
\geq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Bbb P(k|X_1|^\alpha>n)\\
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\Bbb P(|X_n|n^{-1/\alpha}>k^{-1/\alpha})$

So, with probability $1$, $|X_n|n^{-1/\alpha}\leq k^{-1/\alpha}$ eventually. This is true for each $k \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: It should be $\int_0^\infty\Bbb P(k^\alpha|X_1|^\alpha>x)dx$ on the first line? And $\Bbb EX_1 = 0$ can be simply dropped in the statement?

Comment: My $k$ was in the wrong place in the first line. Yes, you can drop the assumption $EX=0$. @onepotatotwopotato

Comment: Hmm... maybe the condition $\Bbb EX_1 =0$ is needed if the statement is replaced to $\lim_{n\to\infty}{S_n\over n^{1/\alpha}} = 0$ a.s.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(|\frac{X_{n}}{n^{1/\alpha}}|>\epsilon)=P(|X_{n}|^{\alpha}>n\epsilon)$$

Thus $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|\frac{X_{n}}{n^{1/\alpha}}|>\epsilon)<\infty$

as $\sum_{n}P(|X_{n}|^{\alpha}>n\epsilon)=\sum_{n}P(|X_{1}|^{\alpha}>n\epsilon)<\infty\iff E(|X_{1}|^{\alpha})<\infty$ due to the precise thing that you wrote in your question. Basically this IS the Integral Test for convergence of a series with decreasing terms.

Hence $\frac{X_{n}}{n^{1/\alpha}}\to 0$ a.s. due to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237423/sufficient-condition-for-almost-sure-convergence#:%7E:text=The%20following%20criterion%20for%20almost,n%E2%86%92X%20almost%20surely.)